# Html element top position varies on high resolution and device pixel ratio

Tags: javascript, css, html, screen-resolution

i need to position 2nd element is next to the first element.So i set top value as 100%. the starting point of 2nd element is varies when device pixel ratio as 1.5.

Machine : Lenovo YOGA 500,
Scale : 150%,
Resolution: 1920 * 1080,
Browser: Except Firefox

```css
.wrap {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ef36d8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}

.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ef36d8;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">Content area</div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

this issue occurs only when device pixel ratio as 1.5.

the arrow class element start position varies based on device pixel ratio.i need to remove border top of red highlighted element

[image: error image]

Kindly guide me any solution on this?

Thanks is advance

Comment: pls add the screenshot how you want

Comment: @Santhoshkumar error screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an interesting problem. The only way I was able to remove that extra line was to have another, slightly smaller div box within the arrow:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">Content area</div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="secondary-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ef36d8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}

.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ef36d8;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.secondary-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 7px;
    left: 51px;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried above solution unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Try and tweak the top value to be a lesser amount, like 98% or something. I don't have your exact device, but using Chrome's device emulator it looks like it works. I did it in this codepen, https://codepen.io/carfen/pen/RLRdaM.